# Event Rich Snippet: location/address for Google Testing Tool

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I'm trying to be friendly to [Google Structured Data Testing tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/). I try to give him an `Event` snippet: https://schema.org/Event

Problem is for `PostalAddress`: I put `itemprop="location"` for my `PostalAddress`, but then it considers that `address` is missing for `PostalAddress`.

I don't know what can I set in an `adress` item, as it is not even described in schema.org.

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
    <h1 itemprop="name">PIÈCE DE THÉÂTRE : " L'AUBERGE DU CARAMEL " DE JEAN-LUC PECQUEUR</h1>
    <ul>
        <li class="avenir"><span itemprop="startDate" content="2015-04-10T20:30:00+02:00">10/04/15</span> 20h30</li>
        <li class="avenir"><span itemprop="startDate" content="2015-04-11T20:30:00+02:00">11/04/15</span> 20h30</li>
        <li class="avenir"><span itemprop="startDate" content="2015-04-12T15:00:00+02:00">12/04/15</span> 15h</li>
    </ul>
    <address>
        <div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
            <span itemprop="name" class="raisoc">PIÈCE DE THÉÂTRE : " L'AUBERGE DU CARAMEL " DE JEAN-LUC PECQUEUR</span>
            <br />
            <span itemprop="streetAddress">route de Paris<br /></span>
            <span itemprop="postalCode">03630</span> <span itemprop="addressLocality">DESERTINES</span>
            <br />
        </div>
    </address>
</div>
```

Comment: For reference, someone on Webmasters has this problem, too: [Google Testing Tool reports error on Schema.org “location”](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/79074/17633)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not clear in the definitions above, but examples are explicit about the usage. Try doing it the below way. snippet tool comes out green.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
    <h1 itemprop="name">PIÈCE DE THÉÂTRE : " L'AUBERGE DU CARAMEL " DE JEAN-LUC PECQUEUR</h1>
    <ul>
        <li class="avenir"><span itemprop="startDate" content="2015-04-10T20:30:00+02:00">10/04/15</span> 20h30</li>
        <li class="avenir"><span itemprop="startDate" content="2015-04-11T20:30:00+02:00">11/04/15</span> 20h30</li>
        <li class="avenir"><span itemprop="startDate" content="2015-04-12T15:00:00+02:00">12/04/15</span> 15h</li>
    </ul>
    <address>
        <div class="event-venue" itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
            <span itemprop="name" class="raisoc">PIÈCE DE THÉÂTRE : " L'AUBERGE DU CARAMEL " DE JEAN-LUC PECQUEUR</span>
            <br />
            <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
            <span itemprop="streetAddress">route de Paris<br /></span>
            <span itemprop="postalCode">03630</span> 
            <span itemprop="addressLocality">DESERTINES</span>
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>
    </address>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, as i said to unor this does not really makes sense as it doesn't respect the schema format but i suppose if google tool validate it, it should be like this ;)

Gonna try to implemente it this way for all pages, thanks a lot ;)

Comment: @PierreGranger, logically speaking place makes sense to me for an event with a name (as all events will take place in a named location)  and address attribute(not just postal address). I would say schema definition is unclear, but their examples reflect what the intention is. I would say going with place attribute is a safe bet here.

Answer (score 1):

This error does not make sense.

You are using the [`location` property](http://schema.org/location) with a [`PostalAddress`](http://schema.org/PostalAddress) item as value, which is fine. It’s appropriate use of the Schema.org vocabulary, and it’s also recommended by [Google’s Event Rich Snippet documentation](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/events).

Now, Google’s Testing Tool reports that Google requires the `address` property for this `PostalAddress` for showing their Event Rich Snippet. But neither is Schema.org’s [`address` property](http://schema.org/address) defined for `PostalAddress` (there can’t be an address of an address), nor does Google list that the `address` property would be required.

It would make sense to use `address` if `Place` is used instead of `PostalAddress`, but it’s plain wrong for `PostalAddress`. Probably Google’s Testing Tool is bugged / confusing this.

Comment: That was my opinion too, but as we do it just for google i suppose i have to make it works for him, even if it's not really correct for schema.

Comment: @PierreGranger: But note that Google’s implementation for their Testing Tool is most likely not what Google Search uses internally for displaying Rich Snippets (so a bug in the Testing Tool is not necessarily also existent in Google Search, and vice-versa). And I’d expect Google to fix this in their Testing Tool as soon as they notice it.

Comment: Yes i know but it's the only way to "correct" the alerts in webmaster tools, wich is the only tool i know for this, even if we can't be sure it will be used or not in results